# Inserting LF(0x0A) in eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, newline

Is there any way to insert LF in eclipse editor?

when I press enter, it appears CR only.

Comment: What kind of file are you editing that is getting a CR (meaning `x0D`, right?) and how did you determine that it's a CR and not a NL/LF (`x0A`) character? That seems like extremely unlikely behaviour.

Comment: Doesn't the mac use <CR> as EOL

Comment: Source file is JSP, and CR(0x0D) appears like ¤ , LF(0x0A) like ¶ in eclipse.

Configuring option could let you see those symbols :
Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Show whitespace characters

Comment: @Marichyasana Old Mac used CR. Modern Unix-based Mac uses LF.

Comment: I just copied whole line that has LF in it and reused LF separated.
Partly solved.